# Adjust UILabel to align to right of screen

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios8, uilabel

Currently I am trying to create a messaging feature in an application.

I am trying to align the UILabel with a message sent from the User to the right side of the screen. As the text width contents increased, I wanted it to stretch to the left side of the screen, then line break once it achieves a max width.

As you can see I have the text line breaking correctly but I cannot get the text to sit on the screen correctly.

My solution to the problem was to adjust the width of the UILabel programmatically, however I have been unable to get it to change from the fixed size I have in the xib file of the custom outgoing message cell

Could someone please advise on how to do this?

EDIT:

I drew boxes over the current bounds of the UILabel to show what it's currently doing
[image: Box drawn over UILabel bounds]

This is the text moved and the UILabel bound redrawn to explain what I am trying to do. 
[image: Box and text moved to show what I'm trying to do.]

Screenshot of app 
[image: Screen shot of messaging feature in application]

Comment: Have you applied text alignment? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel/1620541-textalignment

Comment: @paulvs I made some edits to better explain the problem I am having. I have the text aligned correctly and was my mistake . The problem is the size of the UILabel I am unsure how to change

Comment: So you want to shrink the label to fit its content? Are you using constraints or frames to position the labels?

Comment: @paulvs I am using constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you are supposed to calculate the width of the label based on text length.
Try this API to get size of label based on text input.

CGSize yourLabelSize = [yourLabel.text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:yourLabel.font size:yourLabel.fontSize]}];

or

I am not below would work in your case. but you can give a try.

Create a label in Xcode, use Auto layout to set padding (mostly 4 points on trailing & flexible leading space > 4 points). make sure you set number of lines to "0" and have text aligned to right. Do not set fixed size for width here

Comment: The solution I am seeking is to not to right-justify the text, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can achieve the desired effect by measuring the length of the text and and calling size to fit on the label. Then you offset the frame of the label (or the surrounding superView if desired) to either the left or right side of the screen.

Here's a quick method (probably best to declare variables maxWidth and padding elsewhere). Note that 'w' is a variable for the screen's width.

```
-(UIView *)bubbleWithText:(NSString *)text atOffset:(float)yOff isLeftAligned:(bool)leftAligned {

    float maxWidth = 200.0f;
    float intraCellPadding = 5.0f;

    UILabel * label = [UILabel new];
    label.frame = CGRectMake(intraCellPadding, intraCellPadding, maxWidth, 0);
    label.textColor = (leftAligned) ? [UIColor blackColor] : [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.text = text;
    label.numberOfLines = 0;
    [label sizeToFit];

    float width = label.frame.size.width;
    float height = label.frame.size.height;
    float xOff = (leftAligned) ? intraCellPadding : w-3*intraCellPadding-width;

    UIView * bubble = [UIView new];
    bubble.frame = CGRectMake(xOff, yOff, width + 2 * intraCellPadding, height + 2 * intraCellPadding);
    bubble.backgroundColor = (leftAligned) ? [UIColor greenColor] : [UIColor blueColor];
    bubble.layer.cornerRadius = intraCellPadding;
    [bubble addSubview:label];

    return bubble;

}
```

And you would call the above with something like this:

```
float interCellPadding = 10.0f;
float yOff = 20.0f;
bool previousWasLeft = false;

NSArray * texts = @[@"Bacon ipsum dolor amet kevin swine ham hock, leberkas porchetta salami bacon picanha shoulder pig strip steak sirloin.",
                    @"Short loin hamburger meatloaf jowl, sirloin swine pork belly tail t-bone venison.",
                    @"Flank meatloaf prosciutto ball tip strip steak rump.",
                    @"Short piggy.",
                    @"Tri-tip ribeye drumstick andouille leberkas bacon pork chop meatball pork spare ribs chicken.",
                    @"Strip steak filet mignon tri-tip sausage, cow frankfurter bacon ribeye cupim burgdoggen shank pork belly fatback ham hock."];

for (NSString * text in texts){

    //random assignment left / right
    //by creating a random number, either one or zero
    //this doubles up as a boolean
    bool alignLeft = arc4random_uniform(2);

    //here we increment the offset
    //depending on whether the previous bubble
    //was on the same side or not, giving a
    //bit more space for alternating bubbles.
    yOff += (previousWasLeft != alignLeft) ? interCellPadding : interCellPadding/2.0f;
    previousWasLeft = alignLeft;

    //create the bubble and add
    UIView * bubble = [self bubbleWithText:text atOffset:yOff isLeftAligned:alignLeft];
    [self.view addSubview:bubble]; //or scrollView whatever

    //incrmeent the offset
    yOff += bubble.frame.size.height;

}
```

This is quick and dirty, but shows how to implement what you need. For a lot of cells (which is probably what you want), if you were going the custom route, you'd have to keep an eye on releasing them from memory. It might be easier to adapt a UICollectionView cell and simply align the content within that.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I had this issue and came across this post. How I solved it was just with a little math

```
            //Calculations for how far you want the UILabel from the edge of the screen
            var xScreenVal = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Size.Width - 40;
            var screenWidth = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Size.Width;
            var textWidth = body.Text.StringSize(body.Font).Width;
            var offset = screenWidth - 50 - (xScreenVal + textWidth);
            var distanceFromScreenEdge = offset + xScreenVal;

            //Setting the Frame
            myUILabel.Frame = new CGRect(distanceFromScreenEdge, ContentView.Bounds.Top, textWidth + 25, ContentView.Bounds.Height);
```

This was in Xamarin.ios, but it would translate easily.